# Adding rows and columns on button clicks bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rows, bootstrap-modal, dynamic-columns

I have a requirement where the user should be able to add the rows and columns dynamically in bootstrap table. On button click a new row and an other button click a new columns should appear.

Similarly on button click of '-', the row needs to be deleted and an other button click, column needs to be deleted.

I am new to bootstrap 3. Any guidance will be of great help!!

Comment: you can use javascript and gettable by id and use insertrow function, if you need I can put sample code for you

Comment: Please drop in a sample code, it would be of great help!

Comment: look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: that would be more cooler if even if the content were to change to value still displays. what i mean is that by clicking add button and typing more text it will still be printed out. just saying and by the way your code will help others a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to do that, here's a simple example : 
https://jsfiddle.net/1okx6pja/ 
Html :

```
<button onclick='add()'>
  add
</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>content</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick='rm()'>
          remove
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript :

```
function rm() {
  $(event.target).closest("tr").remove();
}

function add() {
  $("table").append("<tr><td>New Thing</td><td><button onclick='rm()'>remove</button></td></tr>");
}
```

if you don't understand something feel free to ask